# Can I use a DC Power supply that takes in 230V +/-10% on my 220V line without affecting performance?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, mains

Though I hope I could get a general answer but as an example.. I am considering getting a Keysight E6103A Power supply. I live in a country with AC 220V 60Hz mains.

[E6100 Data sheet](http://literature.cdn.keysight.com/litweb/pdf/5992-0914EN.pdf?id=2633187)

Can I use this said power supply that takes in 230V +/-10% on my 220V line without affecting performance or causing any issue?

Does the plus minus 10% mean I could use anywhere between 207V-253V to power the device?

And generally, does this logic apply to anything with plus/minus 10% or whatver percent input?

Thank you for any answer

Comment: (1) You might be better off emailing this question to Keysight.  (2) You should be okay with 220V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data sheet clearly states the requirements: -

> AC Input 100, 115, or 230 V input (± 10%), 47 to 63 Hz, 200 VA power
>   consumption

You have the 230V version therefore the limits that are guaranteed to work are 207 to 253 volts as you state. 60Hz is also acceptable.